# Executing statements with leading periods in pry

Tags: ruby, read-eval-print-loop, irb, pry

Pry interprets a command with a leading `.` as a system command and passes it to shell. However this prevents me from executing blocks of code with lines that have leading `.`, which are very frequent in my code.

In IRB something like below works fine:

```
2.2.3 :001 > begin
2.2.3 :002 >     "hello world"
2.2.3 :003?>       .split(" ")
2.2.3 :004?>       .map(&:upcase)
2.2.3 :005?>   end
 => ["HELLO", "WORLD"]
```

In Pry however:

```
[6] pry(#<MailFetcherService>)> begin
[6] pry(#<MailFetcherService>)*   "hello world"
[6] pry(#<MailFetcherService>)*   .split(" ")
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `" "'
sh: -c: line 0: `split(" ")'
Error: there was a problem executing system command: split(" ")
```

Is there a way to work around this? I am OK with any of the below:

- Interpret `.` as a system command only when there are no leading spaces before it.
- Changing to some other obscure delimiter rather than `.` for system command
- Last resort: System commands are disabled entirely - this is not a feature I use often.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in [Pry's internal wiki](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Command-system#Command_prefix), you have two options:

1. You can either prefix your command with a semicolon so Pry ignores it (messy, in my opinion).
2. You can alter the `config.command_prefix` property (by default an empty string `""`) which will make it so you need to add the new `command_prefix` whenever you want to use System commands.

Example of #2:

```
pry(main)> Pry.config.command_prefix = "%"
=> "%"
pry(main)> ls -l
NameError: undefined local variable or method `l' for main:Object
from (pry):2:in `<main>'
pry(main)> %ls
locals: _  _ex_  _pry_  _in_  _out_  _file_  _dir_
pry(main)>
```

Comment: My primary issue is with trying out blocks of code from my code base to the REPL. If I have to edit individual lines,I might as well change to position of dots.

Comment: Setting the command_prefix does not solve the problem for me. Can you try the example in my question - if it works what is the version of pry that you are using.  I have added it to my `.pryrc` .. executing directly in REPL does not work either.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work for lines starting with periods, which is what the question is about.